# @Import of less files into a limited scope

Tags: css, less

I want to import all styles from another less file, but into a limited scope. I'm trying this:

"my-site.less"

```
.wrapper-class {
    @import "path/to/styles.less";
}
```

But this doesn't work at all. I'm using the browser-based less.js option, and I can see the GET statement that is run when it actually does the import. But the resultant CSS does not contain any of the styles from the other sheet. If I do it like this, it works:

```
.wrapper-class 
{
    /* ... */
}
@import "path/to/styles.less";
```

But this defeats the original purpose. So is there any way to do a limited-scope @import like this in Less? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this recently?  It seems like it now works the way you originally wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [css-spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#at-import), the `@import`-declaration has to come before all other declarations in the css-file. So your `@import` inside the rule is expected to fail. I guess the `@import`ing at the end of the file not failing is goodwill of the browser-vendors.

I guess LESS will abide by the same rules.

EDIT:
the question is, why do you want to have those styles scoped? With proper declarations, this should not be necessary.

Comment: Yes, I wonder if less adheres to the same. The reason I need it scoped is that I am importing all of Twitter-Bootstrap into that space. The site is a long-standing site of over 10 years, with legacy code up the wazoo. I am doing some new development that implements bootstrap, and I want to limit Bootstrap styles to be applied to certain sections of a page and not everywhere else. Otherwise, Bootstrap ends up conflicting with the other styles already in place.

Comment: well, when you think about the `@import` being a simple concatenation, it makes sense, that a nested `@import` does not work. On the other hand, importing it inside a rule, would not help you either. since styles always apply globally. You could use the html5 scoped attribute, but unfortunately that is very poorly supported.

Comment: I'm not sure about when this answer was first written, but as of this comment it is documented that you can @import at any point in a less file and it is valid: http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature

Comment: @Akrikos Welcome to the future (3,5 years later)... ;)

Answer (score 51):

Since this question was posted and answered, pre-processors have implemented @import with scope. This now works in LESS, SASS and Stylus.

example:

```
.lt-ie9 {
  @import "ie8-fixes";
}
```

Comment: Is this documented for LESS and SASS? Here's the Stylus documentation: http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/import.html#block-level-import

Comment: LESS has no docs, as they think this is expected behavior. The github issue is here: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/656 Sass docs:http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested-import

Comment: The Less docs almost say it now: ["Less doesn't care where you put `@import` statements."](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with gulp-less 4.0.0. I get a gulp build error: "Bundle Name" style bundle invalid write callback called multiple times

Answer (score 3):

Times changed.
Now your first code snippet will work.

```
.wrapper-class {
    @import "path/to/styles.less";
}
```

since
https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/656#issuecomment-4219139

Answer (score -5):

The syntax of LESS (and CSS) don't allow `@imports` into CSS rules.
Try use *namespace*:

#### styles.less

```
.styles {
    [your code]
}
```

Then, replace the `@import` for *namespace*:

```
.wrapper-class {
    .styles;
}
```

Reference:

http://lesscss.org/features/