# LESS: Nested Import In Class

Tags: php, compiler-construction, nested, less

I got a lot of less files that are imported into one main less file. That main file has some different variables containing hex-color.

e.g:

```
@black: #333;
@green: #007f4b;
...

@import "layout";
@import "html";
...
```

Is it possbile to do some thing with this base?

e.g:

```
@black: #333;
@green: #007f4b;

@import: "layout";
@import: "html";

.fanshop {
  @black: #111;
  @green: green;

  @import: "layout";
  @import: "html";
}
```

The result should look like:

```
.headline {
  background-color: #333;
}
.fanshop .headline {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

Is this possbile with any less compiler? Currently I'm using lessphp.

Thank you!

Comment: Check this out please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623791/import-of-less-files-into-a-limited-scope

Comment: Arent you missing the import file extensions?

Comment: @Flosculus Naw, lessphp doesn't require the extensions.

Comment: You need to be careful with lessphp.  Many front-end libraries like Bootstrap are compiled with lesscss, but I have experienced issues compiling it myself with lessphp where floating point precision differences with node/php broke the dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in Less (not sure about exact version but most likely since 1.5.x), like this:

```css
@black: #333;
@import "layout";

.fanshop {
    @black: #111;
    @import (multiple) "layout";
}
```

But that won't work in lessphp since it's somewhat behind Less 1.4.x. You could try [less.php](http://lessphp.gpeasy.com/) instead.